# Session Sharing Between Two different Web Applications

Tags: python, c#, session

can i share session between different lang applications like:
1st is based on C# and
2nd is based on python, so can i somehow share session?
if yes can someone please tell me how?

Comment: What do you mean by "share a session"? Are these HTTP servers?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a common means of storing and sharing the data.
This can be your DB or better a shared cache like **Redis**.
Session data can be stored with a session id as a Key.
Then you can store this Key as a Cookie value to the client which will be passed on every request.

One of the most standardized ways of storing this information into the client is [JWT](https://www.google.com/search?q=jwt%20claims&oq=jwt&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i57j69i60l4.1585j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

JWT can be read by almost all kind of server apps.